# Track user through GPS ,ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I need to track the user location through gps.I need to show a polyline along the path ,the user travels.And also need to calculate distancs,speed and elapsed time.Please guide me with some tutorials.

Comment: Apple's Breadcrumb sample demonstrates how to track the user.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048

Answer (score 0):

Retain the user's navigation locations form the following delegate method.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
}
```

By using the following delegate method pass the overlay view.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
if([overlay class] == MKPolyline.class)
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
    MKPolyline* polyline = (MKPolyline *)overlay;
    MKPolylineView  * routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:polyline];

    routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
    routeLineView.lineCap = kCGLineCapSquare;
    overlayView = routeLineView;
    return overlayView;
} else {
    return nil;
}
}
```

For creating polyline, refer the following

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKPolyline

Regards,
Arun.